# List operations in cLISP

Tags: list, struct, lisp

I have the following struct:

```
(defstruct node
  parent
  state
  cost)
```

I have a list of structs of type `node`.

I am trying to implement two functions:

```
(defun findMinimum (list)

returns the node with the smallest cost in the list
)


(defun replaceNode (list)

 Checks if a node with the same state as new-node already exists in the list. 
If so, replaces that node with new-node.
)
```

My current solution is just a loop through the entire list that checks every node. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this in cLISP?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the name of your functions from camelCase to more Lispy style:

```
(defun find-minimum (list)
  (reduce #'min list :key #'node-cost) )
```

For replace-node I guess you need another argument with the new-node. Let's assume that's what you want:

```
(defun replace-node (new-node list)
  (let ((pos-old-node (position (node-state new-node) list :key #'node-state)))
    (when pos-old-node
      (setf (nth pos-old-node list) new-node) )))
```

Comment: You could use `MEMBER` instead of `POSITION` to get the cons cell, and then set the `CAR` of it. That way you don't need to traverse the list again with `NTH`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I make `find-minimum` return the minimum cost node, instead of the minimum value itself?

Comment: @RuiLoureiro You can use a function that compares the costs instead of `MIN`. For example, `(lambda (&optional a b) (when (and a b) (if (<= (node-cost a) (node-cost b)) a b)))`